# AWS ApiGateway Proxy to non-Public S3 Bucket

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

The following cloudformation script sets up an Api Gateway method that proxies to an S3 bucket.

The S3BucketPolicy opens up the bucket to public read access but the AWS UI warns that this should never be done.

I tried setting the S3BucketPolicy `Principal` to service apigateway.amazonaws.com but this results in Access Denied.

1) What is the right way to limit bucket access to the API gateway function? (Sample YAML would be great)

2) How could I debug this Access Denied failure to get more information on why it failed?

3) Where should I be looking for sample code on what should be a very standard template snippet?

**ATTEMPT #1 - Works but only by making the S3 Bucket Public otherwise Access Denied**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Parameters:
  S3BucketName:
    Type: String
    Description: >
      Name for the S3 bucket that contains the nested templates.

Resources:
  RestAPI:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'
    Properties:
      BinaryMediaTypes: 
            - '*/*'
      Name: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'

  RestAPIRootGET:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: GET
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: GET
        PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
        Type: HTTP_PROXY
        Uri: !Sub https://${S3BucketName}.s3.amazonaws.com/static-assets/index.html
      ResourceId: !GetAtt RestAPI.RootResourceId
      RestApiId: !Ref RestAPI
    DependsOn:
      - RestAPI

  BucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref S3BucketName
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          -
            Sid: GetObject
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: "*"
            Action:
              - s3:*
            Resource:
              - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${S3BucketName}/static-assets/*'
```

I think perhaps the right away is to create a role with access to the bucket and then have the ApiGateway assume this role but I'm having a hard time finding documentation that explains how to do this in a cloudformation template. (see also Michael - sqlbot comment suggesting using the credentials property of the method)

Here is my attempt which still fails with Access Denied

**ATTEMPT #2 - Access Denied**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Parameters:
  S3BucketName:
    Type: String
    Description: >
      Name for the S3 bucket that contains the nested templates.


Resources:

  RestAPI:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'
    Properties:
      BinaryMediaTypes: 
            - '*/*'
      Name: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'

  RestAPIRootGET:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: GET
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: GET
        PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
        Type: HTTP_PROXY
        Uri: !Sub https://${S3BucketName}.s3.amazonaws.com/static-assets/index.html
        Credentials: !GetAtt AllowStaticAccessRole.Arn
      ResourceId: !GetAtt RestAPI.RootResourceId
      RestApiId: !Ref RestAPI
    DependsOn:
      - RestAPI
      - AllowStaticAccessRole

  AllowStaticAccessRole: 
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties: 
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument: 
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement: 
          - 
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal: 
              Service: 
                - "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
            Action: 
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Path: "/"
      Policies: 
        - 
          PolicyName: "AllowStaticAccessPolicy"
          PolicyDocument: 
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement: 
              - 
                Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - s3:*
                Resource:
                  - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${S3BucketName}/static-assets/*'
```

Comment: See [`Integration->credentials`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-integration.html) and compare with [`credentials`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/#credentials).  This looks like the place for the ARN of the IAM role that API Gateway needs to assume before contacting S3.  `apigateway.amazonaws.com` would probably be the `Principal` on the trust policy of that role, and the role policy would grant permissions on the bucket.

Comment: I will try this and update

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot. I added an attempt to do as you suggested but still results in "Access Denied"

Comment: Just for anyone else coming here with a similar problem, another possible cause of 'access denied' is if the object in the s3 bucket is encrypted - the role you give to API Gateway has to have permissions to use KMS and the specific key.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments, the Access Denied error could be coming from KMS rather than from the S3 itself.

To solve the issue, you need to add at minimum these permissions to the role that the Api Gateway assumes: `"kms:Decrypt", "kms:ReEncryptFrom"`, preferably also stating which `Resource` this should apply too for proper least privilege implementation.